# UI design error in R programming

Tags: r, user-interface

I run this command in R studio MAC pc

```
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
library(gWidgets)
gmessage("Hello world", title="gmessage")
```

But the output was

> Error: could not find function "message"

How do I fix this?

Comment: From which package comes function `gmessage`?

Comment: @Pascal how do I find that?

Comment: I don't know. You are the one asking the question. `gmessage` is not a standard function. So which package are you loading?

Comment: @Pascal library(gWidgets)

Comment: @Pascal Do you have a MAC pc? If so what version?

Comment: Correct, I am not on MAC. But your error message doesn't seem related to the OS.

Comment: I have a Mac. RGtk2 fails to load. I'm not sure that the more recent versions of OSX are compatible with the GTK2 that is available at the r.research.att.com website. I've tried everything I could to get it installed and keep getting error messages. When I look for `gmessage` usign `sos::findFn` I only find it located in `gWidgets2` rather than `gWidgets`

Comment: @42- I installed XQuartz now it is working. http://www.xquartz.org

Comment: I'm guessing that was on the Snow Leopard branch of R for OSX.

Comment: @Harry: glad it works now. You should definitely be using `gWidgets2` now and not the older `gWidgets`. The differences to the user are slight, but bug fixes for the older one are much less likely to happen.